# Names for specific rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

1. Is there a name for a ring $A$ (commutative with $1 \neq 0$) all of whose ideals are radical?
2. Is there a name for a ring $A$ (commutative with $1 \neq 0$) such that for each $x \in A$, there is $n \geq 2$ such that $x^n = x$?

I am currently calling $A$ in 1 a *radical ring* and $A$ in 2 a *semi-Boolean ring*.

Comment: "Radical ring" apparently already means a (necessarily non-unital) ring which is equal to its own Jacobson radical. Anyway, that first condition seems quite strong. In the second condition, is $n$ fixed or is it allowed to depend on $x$?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use that word then. A Boolean ring $A$ satisfies the first condition since for an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq A$, we have $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}} = \{x \in A : x^{n} \in \mathfrak{a} \text{ for some } n \geq 2\} = \{x \in A : x \in \mathfrak{a}\} = \mathfrak{a}$.

For the second condition, the integer $n \geq 2$ depends on $x$.

Comment: The first condition implies that $A$ is von Neumann regular (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) and I think the converse holds if $A$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's equivalent even without the Noetherian condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm pretty sure that "radical" here means that $\sqrt{I}=I$)

Under the conditions of #1, all ideals of the ring are semiprime. Taking any element $a$, $(aR)^2$ is a semiprime ideal, so it must contain $aR$, and we have proven that $aR=(aR)^2$. Since this says that $a=ara$ for some $r\in R$, we have also shown that $R$ is [von Neumann regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular). An observation that we'll need shortly is that $ar$ is idempotent, and $aR=araR\subseteq arR\subseteq aR$, so $aR=eR$ for an idempotent $e=ar$.

Conversely, if $R$ is von Neumann regular, we can show that all its ideals are semiprime, since they are all idempotent.

As observed before, for any element $a\in R$, there exists an idempotent $e$ such that $eR=aR$. Suppose $I\lhd R$ and $I^2\neq I$. Clearly $aR\subseteq I$, and $(aR)^2\subseteq I^2$. Pick $a\in I\setminus I^2$. Then $(aR)^2=(eR)^2=e^2R=eR=aR$, and that implies that $a\in (aR)^2\subseteq I^2$, a contradiction. Hence $I^2=I$ for all ideals, and $I$ is semiprime (=radical).

It turns out that for commutative rings, being VNR is exactly the same as saying that every ideal is an intersection of *maximal* ideals. As a result, every proper quotient ring of $R$ has zero Jacobson radical. Since Jacobson used "radical ring" to describe a ring in which the Jacobson radical is the *entire* ring, this is an unfortunate conflict with your choice of term. Alternatives appear in the list below.

In the noncommutative case, things separate a bit, and I can tell you some more about terminology.

1. If all ideals are semiprime, the ring is sometimes called **fully semiprime**, and sometimes **fully idempotent**, since all ideals being semiprime is equivalent to having all ideals idempotent. VNR rings are fully idempotent (same proof as above) but clearly not all fully idempotent rings are VNR: there exist non-VNR simple rings which are trivially fully idempotent.
2. If all ideals are the intersection of maximal right ideals, the ring is called a **right V-ring** (where V stands for Villemajor). There are non-VNR V-rings and non-V VNR rings. This is less relevant to your situation than the above point, but interesting enough to mention :)

---

I don't immediately recall a name for condition 2, but I'm sure there is one. Of course, condition 2 implies condition 1. You might be interested to know that you don't have to assume commutativity: a theorem [by Jacobson](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PUZZLES/herstein) proves that if for every $x$ there is $n>1$ such that $x=x^n$, then the ring is commutative.